# Accidentally shorted 5V to GND on Arduino Nano, can I reuse the ATmega328p?

Tags: power, arduino-nano, atmega328

I've shorted 5V to GND and the Arduino Nano (CH340 clone) stopped working (power LED light is dimming). The board had a burning smell, and I also checked if other Arduini on the same USB port worked and they did, so I'm quite sure the Arduino is dead.

After the incident, I de-soldered the TQFP Atmega328p (plus the crystal) to reuse. I'm thinking that if it's only the external circuitry that's damaged, then the chip should be OK. Can I reuse the chip if I solder onto a new board? What components could have been damaged?

Comment: It always depends where you created the short circuit. If it was the VCC and GND pin of the ATmega, then you fried everything else but the MCU.

Comment: The short circuit was near a class D amplifier which I had misplaced on a breadboard. The amplifier and other components survived, only the arduino stopped working.

Comment: Can you show the schematics?

Comment: I don't have the schematics for this, I was just testing a few things. It's was a simple circuit though, just a mp3 player module, some LEDs and the PAM8403 amp.

Comment: Just draw a picture, how you wired up all the things.

Comment: The wiring was fine, I've done the same many times. I just put the amp module in the wrong position and realised the 5V and G input to the module were in the same row, it stayed like that for about 30 seconds until I realised.

Comment: If you shorted VCC with Ground and not Pin with Ground it's possible that just the voltage regulator let out the magic smoke. Did you power the Arduino via USB?

Comment: Yes, it was powered by USB.

Comment: I think the USB connection doesn't use the voltage regulator. I think the easiest for you would be to connect the Nano to USB, take multimeter and check voltage on the Atmega328p pads. If the VCC and GND have 5V they you have 100% certainty that the power circuit works, and MCU is fried. Use datasheet to check pinout http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf

Comment: I just did that without the atmega328p (because I already de-soldered it), it's giving me 3V between the 5v pin and Gnd pin...and the LED power led flashes weakly, dimming. So the power circuit is broken.

Comment: This means that there is a chance that power circuit failing prevented MCU from burning up. It's impossible to verify that without extensive tests of the ATmega. It's also possible that there is "some" damage that will decrease its lifespan. It's a 50cent part. IMHO it's easier/safer to get a new one.

Comment: Great, it's good to know that, thanks Filip. I will keep the MCU in a drawer anyway as spare, but separated from the new ones then.

Comment: Think about preparing yourself an overcurrent protection circuit to put between Arduino and breadboard when you prototype.

Comment: That is a good suggestion, I will check what I can do for this. Thanks.

Comment: is it worth your time to spend hours fixing a part you can replace for $2us?

Comment: Try checking the pcb and components for damage. The only thing I can think of that could get damaged in the situation you described would be a PCB trace that’s blown up.

Comment: I just had the exact same problem (shorting 5V and ground - not even for long) on two nano clones, and strangely but consistently, both nano's still seemed to work. However, I wasn't able to flash them through USB anymore. Flashing them through ISP still worked, though.

Answer (score 1):

On a Arduino Nano, there is a diode that prevents an external 5V source from back feeding into the USB source. If your clone equivalent has that as well, I suspect that is the part that got fried.